# How do you write multiple lines in a .txt with recursion?

Tags: c++, recursion, ofstream

Im a programming student and the Engineer told us to write an algorithm using recursion for the math problem "Hanoi Towers". That is done, Im able to print the instructions on the console, but I need to write the instructions on a .txt file. I have managed to create the file and write the first line of text on it, but the rest doesn't really appear. I really need some help with this guys.

```
using namespace std;

void torresdehanoi(int disco, int torre1, int torre2, int torre3){
    ofstream myFile;
    myFile.open("SolucionTorresDeHanoi.txt");
    if(disco==1){
        myFile<<"Mover disco de Torre "<<torre1<<" a la torre "<<torre3<<endl;
    }
    else{
        torresdehanoi(disco-1, torre1, torre3, torre2);
        myFile<<"Mover disco de Torre "<<torre1<<" a la torre "<<torre3<<endl;
        torresdehanoi(disco-1, torre2, torre1, torre3);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int disco=0, torre1=1, torre2=2, torre3=3;

    cout<<"Con cuanteas piezas desea calcular el algoritmo?"<<endl;
    cin>>disco;
    torresdehanoi(disco, torre1, torre2, torre3);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can make the ofstream object global or pass it as a function parameter, or `freopen` (not recommended).

Comment: I understand you completed the Hanoi Towers program using recursion.  Do you have to also use recursion to write the Hanoi program to a file using recursion?

Comment: @user202729 how do i make it global?

Comment: @ManLaw not necessarily, but that's the best way I could come up with it. Have any suggestion?

Comment: @PedroMonterroso Global variables will cause you to lose marks. Open the file in main and pass the `myFile` variable as a reference parameter.

Comment: @john Depends on how the homework is scored. If it's scored automatically then it doesn't matter.

Comment: Using static variable is also an option.

Comment: @user202729 But then freopen would also be OK, but you recommended against that. I'm recommending not to use a global variable. It's a bad habit for a beginner to get into.

Comment: I didn't say that it's good programming practice, but it doesn't matter if nobody is going to read the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the fstream object from main to make things easy:

```
void torresdehanoi(int disco, int torre1, int torre2, int torre3, ofstream& myFile) {

    if (disco == 1) {
        myFile << "Mover disco de Torre " << torre1 << " a la torre " << torre3 << endl;
    }
    else {
        torresdehanoi(disco - 1, torre1, torre3, torre2, myFile);
        myFile << "Mover disco de Torre " << torre1 << " a la torre " << torre3 << endl;
        torresdehanoi(disco - 1, torre2, torre1, torre3, myFile);
    }
}

int main()
{
    ofstream myFile;

    int disco = 0, torre1 = 1, torre2 = 2, torre3 = 3;

    cout << "Con cuanteas piezas desea calcular el algoritmo?" << endl;
    cin >> disco;

    myFile.open("SolucionTorresDeHanoi.txt");
    if (myFile.is_open()) {
        torresdehanoi(disco, torre1, torre2, torre3, myFile);
        myFile.close();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try not to teach new programmers bad habits, there is no reason to use a global variable here

Comment: @AlanBirtles: Thanks. I will edit to remove global variable